# SVG path not observing aspect ratio

Tags: html, svg

I'm having trouble getting the SVG path to scale to its container:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" 
  viewBox="0 0 16 16" 
  width="16" 
  height="16">
    <path stroke="#000" fill="none" d="M209,15a195,195 0 1,0 2,0zm1,0v390m195-195H15M59,90a260,260 0 0,0 302,0 m0,240 a260,260 0 0,0-302,0M195,20a250,250 0 0,0 0,382 m30,0 a250,250 0 0,0 0-382"></path>
</svg>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FeTv2/1/ - As you can see the path is way too big, and seems to have a top and left offset.

Looks the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) of you SVG is way too small to fit the path you're using. The `viewBox` represents the part of your SVG, that should be shown. The `width` and `height` the represent the dimension of the box, in which the content is shown.

Try a `viewBox` size, that really fits your path like this (may need further adjustments):

```
<svg height="16" width="16" 
     viewBox="0 0 450 450" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M209,15a195,195 0 1,0 2,0zm1,0v390m195-195H15M59,90a260,260 0 0,0 302,0 m0,240 a260,260 0 0,0-302,0M195,20a250,250 0 0,0 0,382 m30,0 a250,250 0 0,0 0-382" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
</svg>
```

Additionally, you may (or may not) want to adjust the size of the `<svg>` element.

[**Example Fiddle (big `<svg>`)**](http://jsfiddle.net/FeTv2/2/)

[**Example Fiddle (16x16 `<svg>`)**](http://jsfiddle.net/FeTv2/3/)

Comment: But I want the SVG to be displayed as a 16x16 graphic. That's the point of getting the whole thing to scale to it's 'width' and 'height' attributes, no?

Comment: @Orolin The just adjust the `viewBox` and keep the dimensions of the `<svg>` small.